# Why the local variables are always strong?

Tags: objective-c, variables, block

1. According to the notes in class, it is said that the local variables are always strong. I really wonder the reason for it. Why the local variables are always strong.
2. BTW, I am learning blocks. As far as I know, the local variables is supposed to be used and declared inside the method or blocks. However, the local variables I see when using blocks are declared outside the method, but used inside the block. Therefore, I am really curious about it.

The code where the local variable is outside the method looks like this:

```
_block BOOL stoppedEarly = NO; // this is the local variable
double stoppedValue = 52;
[aDictionary enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock: ^(id key, id value, BOOL *stop) {
NSLog (@"value for key %@ is %@", key, value);
if ([@"ENOUGH" isEqualToString: key] || [value doubleValue] == stoppedValue) {
*stop = YES;
stoppedEarly = YES;
} 
}];
```

Comment: Your question seems to be about two completely different topics. Ask one question per post.

Comment: Besides, I have searched many answers, and in my point of view an argument is a kind of expression where the value will be passed in when calling a method, whereas a parameter is a part of method when declaring this method. However, I still mix them up when reading the iOS apple developer materials. For example:

    int (^myBlock) (int) = ^(int num) {return num * multiplier;};

According to iOS developer material on apple's website, the second int in the parenthesis, (int) is a single argument. However, I think it should be a parameter, because it is in the process of declaring something.

Comment: "parameter" and "argument" are the same thing. Both terms might be used more often in some contexts (e.g. method parameters vs command line arguments) but there is no difference between them.

Answer (score 0):

1) it just makes sense for local variables to be strong, otherwise all objects would be released right after the creation or you would have to add the `__strong` attribute everytime yourself:

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] init];
//if it wasn't a strong reference, view would be released here
//and you couldn't use the reference in the next line
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

2) the Block in your example gets called once for every key-value-pair in the dictionary. Since the intention of the code is to use one variable for all blockcalls, it is declared outside of it. Think of global variables and methods.

Edit: here are some basic examples on scopes of variables.

```
//global, visible in all methods
NSInteger globalVariable; 

- (void)someMethod{
    //local, visible only until the end of the method 
    NSInteger localMethodVariable;

    void (^block)() = ^void() {
         //local, visible only until the end of the block
         NSInteger localBlockVariable;

         //may use all 3 variables here
    };

    //may use globalVariable and localMethodVariable here
}

- (void)someOtherMethod{
     //may use globalVariable here
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! Therefore, the variables in the block: _block BOOL stoppedEarly = NO; and: double stoppedValue = 52; are a kind of global variable instead of local variable?

Comment: Kind of... They are still local in the method declaring them but "global" to the blocks using them

Comment: Feel so sorry for mixing local variables and global variables. If local variables are strong and should be allocated like this: UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] init]; Therefore, the variables defined outside the block are not local variables. Is that right? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I've added some example to clarify the scopes of variables. Hope it helps.